# Is there a way to disable "remove source branch" default option?

Tags: gitlab

We are working on Gitlab and each time I start merging a branch, Gitlab makes the option "Remove source branch" checked by default (which is -I think- dangerous).

[image]

As I don't guarantee that me or a colleague can forget to uncheck this option and make the mistake of removing the branch, I'm wondering if there is a solution to make it unchecked by default (which is -I think- will be more secure)?

Comment: Hi, any reason to not remove source branch? I'm googling but can't find answers.

Comment: I'd like to find a way to make this default to disabled for new/forked projects. Hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only makes it checked by default if you check it during the creation of the merge request. If you uncheck it there, it should not be checked in the resulting merge request.

It was set to default to false in 9.3.5: [Gitlab 9.3.5 Release notes](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/07/05/gitlab-9-dot-3-dot-5-released/)

In the years that went by this was changed and in current releases of GitLab changing it afterwards *is* now possible. See @exud 's anwser.

Comment: thank @marcolz but I didn't checked anything during the creation of the merge request. The only options I have when creating a marge request are: Title, Description, Assignee, Milestone, Labels, Source branch, Target branch. No way to check or uncheck that option.

Comment: Are you maybe running an older version ? Which version of gitlab are you using ? in `9.3.5` and `9.3.6` I do get a checkbox just above the submit button.

Comment: I'm using `GitLab Community Edition 9.2.2` found by checking `gitlab.mydomain/help`

Comment: Please upgrade it (to 9.3.6). That will fix your problem.

Comment: Can this default be changed? More specifically, can the check on the merge request creation page be checked by default?

Answer (score 38):

1. Go to `Settings` > `General` > `Merge requests`
2. Uncheck the box: `Enable 'Delete source branch' option by default`

This option is only available for the maintaniner role.

Comment: I just spend like half an hour searching for this option and I just realized that "developer" role doesn't have access to this option, but "maintainer" does.